# Used kotlin-spring plugin, still getting class not open error

Tags: spring, gradle, kotlin

I am getting a class cannot be final, needs to be open, despite adding the kotlin-spring plugin. The whole purpose of the plugin is to not manually add the open keyword to every class.

Please guide me on getting the Kotling-Spring plugin to work with code below.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.1.2"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: "kotlin-spring"
apply plugin: "kotlin-noarg"
apply plugin: "idea"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.8.RELEASE"
    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:4.3.8.RELEASE"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    fun game(): Game {
        return BaseballGame(redSox(),cubs())
    }

    @Bean
    fun redSox(): Team {
        return RedSox()
    }

    @Bean
    fun cubs(): Team {
        return Cubs()
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Configuration class 'AppConfig' may not be final. Remove the final modifier to continue.
Offending resource: AppConfig
```

REF: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#plugin-and-versions

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem. Enabling annotation processing in Intellij solved the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem. Couldn't run from IDE, but `gradlew.bat build bootRun` worked. Solved by updating Kotlin plugin **in IDEA**, from 1.2.40 to 1.2.41.

Answer (score -4):

I too faced Similar Issue while Running Springboot Application . Finally I learnt that Kotlin Class are final by Default . You need to add **open** before class Name

So , you need to change class modifier as follows :

> open class AppConfig {

Reference :

http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/spring-boot-application-with-kotlin/