# Spring Tool Suite: @Configuration class may not be final. Remove the final modifier to continue

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I am unable to launch my spring boot kotlin app, due to the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Configuration class 'TestApplication' may not be final. Remove the final modifier to continue.
```

I know that @configuration and @bean classes cannot be final so I add the allopen plugin in my pom file:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                </args>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If I package my application and run it (java -jar) it works, but when I try to launch it from STS it won't work.

Kotlin version: 1.2.71
Kotlin eclipse plugin: 0.8.13
STS: 3.9.5

Answer (score 18):

This Question Can be Duplicate of :

[IntelliJ Idea 2017.3 unable to start Kotlin Spring Boot App - @Configuration class may not be final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544015/intellij-idea-2017-3-unable-to-start-kotlin-spring-boot-app-configuration-cla)

or

[Used kotlin-spring plugin, still getting class not open error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335371/used-kotlin-spring-plugin-still-getting-class-not-open-error/56410118#56410118)

. 
Anyways , I Just found Solution

You Just need to add open modifier to TestApplication kotlin class

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class TestApplication
```

might Solve your Issue .

Comment: When you say it could be a duplicate, please flag the post instead.

Comment: The above Questions are Similar , So didn't flagged

Comment: Add the open modifier to the methods as well.

Comment: Isn't this what kotlin-maven-allopen is for?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You must configure the `Kotlin` plugin under `Preferences > Kotlin > Compiler` and enable `Compiler plugins` spring.

[Kotlin Compiler Configuration Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqTr6.png)

Comment: Do you know where this setting is in the new version of IntelliJ? There is no 'Compiler plugins' in Kotlin Compiler screen now.

Comment: @Frappuccino Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Kotlin Compiler